# Select some pairs of numbers, C#

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

It is given set of pairs of numbers, for example:

```
(2,0)
(2,1)
(3,1)
(0,0)
(4,1)
(4,2)
(4,3)
```

I want to pick (select) those pairs which do not have same second number.
For example, I need pair (2,1) or (3,1) or (4,1) not all three and not two of the these three, then I need (0,0) or (2,0) not both, and of course I need to select (4,2) and (4,3). How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

if it's a `Tuple<int,int>`, you can do a group by the 2nd item, `Item2`, something like below:

```
var data = new List<Tuple<int,int>>();

var result = from d in data group d by d.Item2 into g select new {g.First()}
```

If not a `Tuple` you can still apply the same logic to other data structure